# OpenERP 7.0 xml tag <group> explained

Tags: odoo

As far as I know there was fundamental change of xml tag `<group>` between versions 6.x and 7.0. Could somebody explain or point to a resource where I could read how this tag behaves in OpenERP 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a definitive doc although I vaguely remember reading something on Launchpad but I can't find it now.  The [developer docs](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/form-view-guidelines/) have this:

> Technically, the layout of forms version 7.0 is different than former
>   versions. There is no longer a default “grid” layout; instead the
>   layout is more based on HTML and CSS. The following conventions are
>   now used:
>
> ```
> The elements <form> and <page> no longer define groups; the elements inside are laid out inline. One should use explicit <div> or
> ```
>
> to create blocks.
>
> ```
> By default, the element <group> now defines two columns inside, unless an attribute col=”n” is used. The columns have the same width
> ```
>
> (1/n th of the group’s width). Use a  element to produce a
>   column of fields.
>
> ```
> The element <separator string=”XXX”/> on top of a group can be replaced putting string=”XXX” inside the <group> element.
>
> The element <field name=”XXX”/> does not produce a label, except when they are directly below a <group> element. Use <label for=”XXX”/>
> ```
>
> to produce the label of the field.

I have found sometimes I need to define a top level group inside the form and then use groups inside that with the regular col and colspan attributes.  Possibly the best is to find a form that matches what you are trying to achieve and see how it does it.

There is also the new, annoying sheet attribute as well, I just don't understand this one (I mean I don't understand why, I know what it does).

Comment: Upvote for good reference point. Btw, I believe they introduced sheet, because if you print an object in form view, it looks just like the form on your screen. But it's a bit annoying if you have FullHD monitor, cuz you get a lot of unoccupied space.